# Is XBMC an operating system?

Tags: operating-systems, kodi

Is [XBMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBMC) for the Raspberry Pi an operating system?

Or is it built on top of another, such as [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XBMC is not an operating system, but a cross-platform media player. It needs an existing operating system in order to be installed and run.

From the XBMC website:

> XBMC is an award-winning free and open source (GPL) software media
>   player and entertainment hub for digital media. XBMC is available for
>   Linux, OSX, and Windows. Created in 2003 by a group of like minded
>   programmers, XBMC is a non-profit project run and developed by
>   volunteers located around the world. More than 50 software developers
>   have contributed to XBMC, and 100-plus translators have worked to
>   expand its reach, making it available in more than 30 languages.

Answer (score 3):

Just a little addition to IRO-bot's answer, someone has bundled XMBC together as image for the Raspberry Pi: http://www.raspbmc.com/about/

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the addition: I tried Raspbmc/XBMC to connect to my [Plex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plex_%28software%29) media server on my [Synology NAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synology_Inc.#Synology_DiskStation). I'm surprised how well it performs.

In fact, it performed so well it became my main media player, and I bought a new Raspberry Pi for my other projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Raspbmc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_based_on_XBMC#Raspbmc), [XBian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_based_on_Kodi_and_XBMC#XBian) or [OpenELEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenELEC) for [XBMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBMC) on the Raspberry Pi. They all compile a Raspberry Pi version based on [Raspbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Software) that is single focussed on performance on the Raspberry Pi. I have found so far that Raspbmc is the most feature rich, but XBian is rocking too.